# Java fabric8 Kubernetes-client: Any way of getting 'kubectl describe'?

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubectl, fabric8

I'd like to programmatically get a printout similar to 'kubectl describe pod...' without using the command line. I'd like to ensure there is not a direct way to do it before starting to collect all the info together from a Pod and trying to code a similar format by myself.

I haven't found any example in https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/tree/main/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples nor searching in forums.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A useful trick is to issue the command with a high log-level to see which API calls are being made. You can try `kubectl describe pod/{pod} --namespace={namespace} --v=6 > /dev/null` to see the calls (and swallow the regular output). In this case: `/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{pod}` and `api/v1/namespaces/ackal/events?fieldSelector={fieldSelector}` where `{fieldSelector}` is a URL-encoded value. To reproduce this functionality using Kubernetes SDKs, you'll need to use the equivalent methods in the SDK.

Comment: Thanks. I can see 3 calls: 2 times the call for the pod and 1 time a call for the events. I already supposed that they were necessary to create a "describe" result by myself, but my concern is if there is any method or class in the SDK that could compose something similar without having to deal with String formats, spaces, columns, etc.

Comment: `kubectl` makes the calls to the Kubernetes API and it (`kubectl`) assembles the output. What you see in the logs is what `kubectl` receives. So, if anywhere, you'd find the code to assemble the output in `kubectl`.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, DazWilkin. Finally I spent some hours in coding something similar. It's a pity :(